# my servlet was working fine earlier but now it cant connect to mysql server and gives me an error

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

so yesterday my servlet was running just fine and i could fetch info from my locally hosted mysql database.
But today all of a sudden i get the following exception

> com.mysql.jdbc.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure due to underlying exception: ** BEGIN NESTED EXCEPTION ** java.net.ConnectException MESSAGE: Connection refused STACKTRACE: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method) at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:339) at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:200) at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:182) at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392) at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:579) at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:528) at java.net.Socket.(Socket.java:425) at java.net.Socket.(Socket.java:241) at com.mysql.jdbc.StandardSocketFactory.connect(StandardSocketFactory.java:256) at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.(MysqlIO.java:271) at com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.createNewIO(Connection.java:2771) at com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.(Connection.java:1555) at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:285) at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:571) at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:215) at Database.getConnection(Database.java:18) at SelectionAlgorithm.execute(SelectionAlgorithm.java:13) at FirstServlet.init(FirstServlet.java:36) at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158) at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1269) at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1182) at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.allocate(StandardWrapper.java:853) at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:134) at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:110) at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:506) at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:169) at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103) at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:962) at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116) at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:452) at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1087) at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:637) at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:316) at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) ** END NESTED EXCEPTION ** Last packet sent to the server was 1 ms ago. at com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.createNewIO(Connection.java:2847) at com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.(Connection.java:1555) at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:285) at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:571) at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:215) at Database.getConnection(Database.java:18) at SelectionAlgorithm.execute(SelectionAlgorithm.java:13) at FirstServlet.init(FirstServlet.java:36) at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158) at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1269) at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1182) at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.allocate(StandardWrapper.java:853) at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:134) at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:110) at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:506) at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:169) at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103) at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:962) at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116) at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:452) at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1087) at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:637) at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:316) at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

i tried connecting to the database via terminal and its working just fine, am using sequel Pro as a GUI tool for managing my database, it also connects just fine. so i cant stop wondering what the problem might be.
i tried checking th firewalls, everything is okey.

also below is the url i use to connect to the database

```
DB_URL="jdbc:mysql://localhost/pickdatabase";
```

NOTE: i know the url is missing the port number but its been working just fine for the past week without using the port number. So i tried including the port number as well(3306) but it still doesnt work, i even tried using "127.0.0.1" instead of "localhost" in the URL but it still doesnt work.

Comment: The _Connection refused_ in the stacktrace indicates that either MySQL is not running, not listening on port 3306 on localhost, or the connection is actively blocked by the firewall.

Answer (score 0):

To me this sounds like it's a permissions or firewall issue. What is the computer that the database is housed on? I would also double check whether or not the IP that you are connecting from has a mysql user that has permissions to connect. You will likely have to add a root user with all permissions this command is start

```
CREATE USER 'newuser'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
```

Comment: yes i know it sounds like a firewall issue but its not. i checked a couple of times. Plus my user has all privileges on the database. like i said it was working fine before and i didnt change anything related to the database. when i use other tools like sequel pro to connect to the database it works fine